# Does FCM send push notification dicrectly or it sends message to APNS?

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

As per the Apple documentation, every push notification always traverse through the `APNS` server. I have heard somewhere that `FCM` directly sends push notification directly to the device i.e. without contacting to the `APNS` server.

If ultimately `APNS` is responsible to send push notification, then why we should use `FCM` for iOS ?

[image]

Comment: Yes, No one can send push except APNS

Comment: Thanks @SPatel..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea behind using Firebase Cloud Messaging to deliver push notifications to both Android and iOS devices is that implementing one server-side interface that sends all your push notifications (regardless of the platform) to one end-point should require less effort than implementing 2 server-side interfaces each sending to a different end-point and implementing a different API.

This is true regardless of whether or not FCM forwards the iOS messages to APNS or delivers them directly to the iOS devices.

Comment: That is true Eran, but I am very curious to know whether it sends through APNS or directly ?

Comment: @NSPratik based on what I read, FCM uses APNS to deliver the messages.

Comment: No PNS provider delivers messages directly to devices, they all go through APNS (in case of iOS). There is no way around this.